# How can the isGenderMatch be compared?

Tags: swift

I am trying to select the user and compare their gender, since the scheduled appointment with the gynecology specialty cannot be with the user who would be male, since that specialty is only for the female gender. I am comparing them and being a woman I should not get the urlAlert message that I have placed, but even so I still get the UrlAlert

this is the message that comes out according to the condition but it still comes out when the gender is female

```
@objc func handleConfirmar(){
    
    guard isGenderMatch == "false" else {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "SANNA", message: "Sexo no corresponde a la especialidad.¿Desea ir a la sección mi cuenta para registrar un nuevo familiar?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .default, handler: { action in
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sí", style: .default, handler: { action in
            
            let miCuenta = MiCuentaViewController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(miCuenta, animated: true)

        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        
        return 
    }
```

I validate them here

```
 @objc func reFreshPicker(){
    
    isGenderMatch = "true"
    isAgeMatch = ""
    
    print("entro")
    
    if let especialidad = nombrePicker.pickedElement as? Especialidad{
      let gender = especialidad.getGender()
            
        let maxAge = especialidad.getMAxAge()
        let minAge = especialidad.getMinAge()
        
        //guard let mainUsuario = UserDefaults.getUser() else {return}
        //select the user
        let sexo = self.SelectUSerGender
        
        if(gender == "" || gender == " "){
            isGenderMatch = "false"
        }
        else{
            if(gender != sexo){
                isGenderMatch = "true"

            }else{
                isGenderMatch = "false"
            }

        }
```

This is my specialty:(Especialidad) class
class Especialidad: PickerType, SearchFilter {
func displayText() -> String {
return especialidad ?? ""
}

```
func pickerText() -> String {
    return especialidad ?? ""
}

var idEspecialidad: String?
var especialidad: String?

var edadMin: String?
var edadMax: String?
var genero: String?

func getGender() -> String{
    return genero ?? ""
}


func getMinAge() -> String{
    return edadMin ?? ""
}


func getMAxAge() -> String{
    return edadMax ?? ""
}



init(dictionary: [String: Any]){
    self.idEspecialidad = dictionary["idEspecialidad"] as? String
    self.especialidad = dictionary["especialidad"] as? String
    self.edadMin = dictionary["edadMin"] as? String
    self.edadMax = dictionary["edadMax"] as? String
    self.genero = dictionary["genero"] as? String
}

init(idEspecialidad: String?, especialidad: String?) {
    self.idEspecialidad = idEspecialidad
    self.especialidad = especialidad
}

static func all() -> Especialidad{
    return Especialidad(idEspecialidad: "", especialidad: "Todas las Especialidades")
}

static var allNil: Especialidad {
    return Especialidad(idEspecialidad: nil, especialidad: "Todas las Especialidades")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Bool` for `isGenderMatch`, and you should start the `refreshPicker` function by setting a `false` value, not `true`, otherwise any failure to get data results in you assuming you have a match.

If you set a breakpoint in `refreshPicker` and step through the code you will see where the problem is. It's hard to say without seeing your data values, but this code looks the wrong way round:

```swift
if(gender != sexo) {
    isGenderMatch = "true"
} else {
    isGenderMatch = "false"
}
```